# Case Class naming convention

Tags: naming, coding-standards, scala

In my recent adventures in **Scala**, I've found **case classes** to be a really nice alternative to enums when I need to include a bit of logic or several values with them. I often find myself writing structures that look like this, however:

```
object Foo{
  case class Foo(name: String, value: Int, other: Double)

  val BAR = Foo("bar", 1, 1.0)
  val BAZ = Foo("baz", 2, 1.5)
  val QUUX = Foo("quux", 3, 1.75)
}
```

I'm primarily worried here about the naming of the object and the case class. Since they're the same thing, I end up with `Foo.Foo` to get to the inner class. Would it be wise to name the case class something along the lines of `FooCase` instead? I'm not sure if the potential ambiguity might mess with the type system if I have to do anything with subtypes or inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested Class Foo.Foo is not the same class as Foo and there is no ambiguity. The case class Foo (the inner one) can only be accessed by it's complete name (Foo.Foo). But:

If you 'import Foo._' or 'Foo.Foo' you will run into trouble. One Solution is to use

```
import Foo.{Foo => InnerFoo}
```

Or you don't import anything and use the complete Path (Foo and Foo.Foo). Does this answer you question?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I was running into confusion and trouble by importing Foo._. Didn't think to alias it.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala there exist [package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html). Thus, there is no need for searching a new name:

```
package foo {
  case class Foo(name: String, value: Int, other: Double)
}
package object foo {
  val Bar = Foo("bar", 1, 1.0)
  val Baz = Foo("baz", 2, 1.5)
  val Quuz = Foo("quux", 3, 1.75)
}
```

Later you can import them with:

```
import foo._
// use all members of package `foo` and package object `foo`
```

Btw, constants are usually named UpperCamelCase (as shown in my example).

Comment: Ah, neat. Didn't know about these. +1 for enlightening me to something that seems helpful, if not immediately then at least in the near future.